# 2dm data disappears after rotating layout in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layouts, mapping, rotate, mesh

I ran into a bug (I suppose) recently. After loading a *.2dm format mesh (triangulated irregular network with elevation data), with the Layer --> Add Layer --> Add Mesh Layer command, I put some data on it (2D water flow vectors and absolute speed to colorize it) and after created a Layout with a Map to export as pdf.

However, when I alter the Map Rotation property on a Map item in the Layout, the Mesh data disappears. So basically any rotation other than 0 degree makes the vectors, and colour disappear (it still shows the triangulation).

It shows again immediately after I put it back to 0 rotation.

Any ideas what's happening here?

Answer (score 1):

It is known bug in the Mesh Layer implementation, keep an eye on https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/35147